# Migration of 32-bit SQL Express 2008 database to 64-bit SQL Server 2008 Standard

Tags: sql-server-2008

Are there any known issues in migrating a SQL Express 2008 database to SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard (x64)?  Has anybody done it?  I have finally convinced my boss that it would be beneficial to migrate our appliance from Windows XP to Windows Server 2008 R2.  Since there is only x64 Server R2, I would like to use SQL Server 2008 x64.

Any shared experiences would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really should be no problem. I've done various upgrades, from SQL2005x32, SQL2008x32, all to SQL2008R2x64, hardly encountering any trouble. Be sure to have a fallback plan, just in case, other than that there should be no more to it than detaching-moving-reattaching (or backup from old server and restore to new) the databases, moving users and Agent jobs and running UPDATE STATS afterwards.
Moving users might be the longest part, there are sql scripts on the web that automate the task.